# store objects in array and show them (Java)

Tags: java, oop, jframe

I am working on a java tic tac toe game. First, I created a class for buttons, I then tried to store an array of instances of that class. Everything was working fine until I added those objects to the frame. Here is my code:

```
package tictactoe;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class TicTacToe extends JFrame
{

    TicTacToe()
    {
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(500,500);    
        this.setBackground(Color.blue);


         PlayingButton[] b = new PlayingButton [9];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)
        {
             b[i] = new PlayingButton();
        }
        b[0].setBounds(0,0,50,50);
        b[1].setBounds(50,0,50,50);
        b[2].setBounds(100,0,50,50);
        this.add(b[0]);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TicTacToe board = new TicTacToe();

    }

}
```

The line that is causing me problems:

```
this.add(b[0]);
```

Comment: And then, what happens? What do you expect the code to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: What is `PlayingButton`? What happened? Is there a stack trace? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: PlayingButton is another class i created it to take an objects from it .

Comment: @M-AmrMoussa Yes, but how are we supposed to find a problem with it if we can't see how it was coded? You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PlayingButton class should extend JComponent or it's subclasses.